# TCPDF produce blank page on selected records from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, tcpdf

I need help.

i'm trying to prepare a pdf out from DB, but it turns out blank. The pdf is table formatted with individual in-line styles. Table design has very complicated conditions such as rows & column merge based on certain criteria as requested by client.

here is what i have found out during the tests:

1. small amount of record fetch from DB - pdf displays perfectly
2. huge amount of record fetch from DB - pdf display blank (no other error on screen, just plain white pdf with header & footer as set in coding)
3. if huge amount of record, echo out in HTML only - all record displayed with table formatting-perfectly.

what i have done:
increased time limit, execution time, used get_ob_contents & all the ob family and most of the solution i found in stackflow as google directed, yet i dont find a solution.

i have all the sql result stored in an array, as I have to do sorting based on certain field which has a sort order from another table (many left join in the sql). instead of adding on to the left join i thought of using array_multisort with the selected field. The pdf is generated based on sql query which has multiple left join and where clause set by use in html form. once the array_multisort has completed only then for loop is set to spread out the variables for pdf execution using writeHTML()

test examples:

1. sql result with less record  (estimate:20 records during test) pdf is generated perfectly with page breaks and page numbering.
2. sql result with many record (149) pdf with plain white single page with only header & footer appears

i can't seem to find a solution to display pdf of huge sql data with table formatting.

Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

btw, i was using TCPDF version 6.2.9 which gave me the headache above so i downloaded 6.3.1 and same result.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',"On");

//require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
$original_mem=ini_get('memory_limit');
ini_set('memory_limit','340M');
session_start();
ob_start();

// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path). 
include '../../dbc.php';
include '../../func.php';

function conditional_format($data){
    //function for conditional formatting
    //with table row structure 
return $formatted_data;
}

require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
// Increase max_execution_time. If a large pdf fails, increase it even more.
ini_set('max_execution_time', 180);
// Increase this for old PHP versions (like 5.3.3). If a large pdf fails, increase it even more.
ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', 1000000);
    




//below function to set footer align in middl of page
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    public function Header() {

        $curdate=date("d/m/Y");
        // get the current page break margin
        $bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();
        // get current auto-page-break mode
        $auto_page_break = $this->AutoPageBreak;
        // disable auto-page-break
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
        if($this->page==1){
            //client requested title only on first page
            $this->Cell(0, 9, 'TRADEMARK STATUS REPORT', 'B', false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
        }
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 10);
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
        $this->setPageMark();
    }

    public function Footer() {
        $curdate=date("d/m/Y");
            // Position at 10 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-10);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'as at '.$curdate, 'T', false, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage(), 'T', false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    
    }
}

//call custom page foooter from function above
$pdf=new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Ryan');
$pdf->SetTitle('Trade Mark Status Report');
$pdf->SetSubject('Trade Mark');
$pdf->SetKeywords('Trade Mark, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);


// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
   $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', 'B', 20);

// add a page
$pdf->setHeaderFont(array('', 'B', 14));
$pdf->AddPage('L', 'A4');

$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 8);

$main_sql="SELECT ..... WHERE 
$user_emtered_where_clause";

//echo $main_sql;
// there is no issue with sql when echo

$result=mysqli_query($db,$main_sql);
$tbl="";
if(!$result){
    echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($db);
}else{
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while($main_rs=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            //get record data from DB
            // design tbl header with selected record 
            $tbl = <<<EOF
            
            <table width="950" v-align="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;font-size:13px;table-layout:fixed;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="950" colspan="7" style="padding:3px;text-align:center;background-color:lightgray;border-bottom:1px solid black;"><h2 style="font-weight:bold;line-height:20px;">$ProjectCompany</h2>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="950"  colspan="7" style="font-size:17px;font-weight:bold;vertical-align:top;"><br>
                            $TMClient
                        </td>                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="30" style="text-align:center;border-left:1px solid black;border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black;border-top:1px solid black;background-color: azure;font-weight:bold;">No</td>
                        <td width="100" style="text-align:center;border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black;border-top:1px solid black;background-color: azure;font-weight:bold;">Filing Country</td>
                        <td width="175" style="text-align:center;border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black;border-top:1px solid black;background-color: azure;font-weight:bold;">Applicant/Proprietor</td>
                        <td width="100" style="text-align:center;border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black;border-top:1px solid black;background-color: azure;font-weight:bold;">Trademark No</td> 
                        <td width="205" style="text-align:center;border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black;border-top:1px solid black;background-color: azure;font-weight:bold;">Trademark</td>
                        <td width="80"  style="text-align:center;border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black;border-top:1px solid black;background-color: azure;font-weight:bold;">Status</td>
                        <td width="260" style="text-align:center;border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black;border-top:1px solid black;background-color: azure;font-weight:bold;">Remarks</td>                                    
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>             
    EOF;
        
        //assign data to array           
      
        $data_array[]=array(all record data here);// assign to array
            
        
    }
    
    //sort array
    foreach ($data_array as $key => $row){
        $sort_country[$key] = $row['sort'];
        //to get the sort order value from array
    }
    // rearrange the array based on the sort order value above
    array_multisort($sort_country, SORT_ASC, $data_array);
    //view array data
     //echo "<pre>";
     //print_r($data_array);
     //echo "</pre>":
     // array data all appear perfect.
    
    if(count($data_array)>0){
        
        $n=1;
        // construct table body data
        foreach($data_array as $item){
            set_time_limit(60);
            
            $no =$n;
            //------------------------ construction of table body -----------------------------------
            
                $class_data= conditional_format($classid); // call conditional format function with variable from $data_array    
                
            $pbreak=$conditional_page_break;
            $tbl_data .= <<<EOD
            $pbreak  

                    <tr nobr="true">
                        <td width="950"  padding="0" style="text-align:left;"><table width="950" style="font-size:13px;table-layout:fixed;border:1px solid red;" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">                                
                                
                                <tr nobr="true">
                                    <td width="30" height="105" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;border-top:1px solid black;border-left:1px solid black;border-right: 1px solid black;">$no</td>
                                    <td width="100" height="105" v-align="top" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;border-top:1px solid black;border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black;">$TMCountry</td>
                                    <td width="175" height="105" v-align="top" style="text-align:left;border-top:1px solid black;border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black;">$TMEffecOwner</td>
                                    <td width="100" height="105" v-align="top" style="vertical-align:top;border-top:1px solid black;text-align:center;border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black;">$TMApplnNo</td> 
                                    <td width="205" height="105" style="text-align:center;word-wrap: break-word;border-top:1px solid black;border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black;"><br><br>$logo $imgType</td>
                                    <td width="80" height="105" v-align="top" style="border-top:1px solid black;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black;">$Status</td>
                                    <td width="260" height="105" v-align="top" style="border-top:1px solid black;vertical-align:top;border-right:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black;">$Remarks</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                                                
                    <tr nobr="true">
                        <td width="950" align="center" style="text-align: center; padding:0px;"><table width="950" v-align="top" style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto; font-size:13px;padding:3px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="30" style="border-left:1px solid black;border-right:1px solid black;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td width="100" style="border-left:1px solid black;font-weight:bold;background-color:#F3F3F3;">Class: &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td width="820" style="border-right:1px solid black;font-weight:bold;background-color:#F3F3F3;">Specification: &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                $class_data
                            </table>
                        </td>                                                    
                    </tr> 
                        
                              
        EOD;
            $n++;
            $linecount++;
            }
        
        }else{
            $tbl= "no record";
        }
    }   
    $tbl.=$tbl_data."
                            </tbody> 
                        </table>
                        ";
$tbl_decode=ob_get_contents();
$pdf->SetY(10);
ob_end_clean();
//echo $tbl_decode; //this echo does produce HTML version of entire table
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl_decode, true, false, false, false, ''); // this is where I get blank pdf page
$pdf->Output('Trademark_Status_Report_with_spec.pdf', 'I');

    ini_set('memory_limit',$original_mem);

?>
```

Comment: this seems to be weird... please provide us with your PHP sample code to generate the PDF and initializing the TCPDF!!

Comment: code uploaded. i had trouble with the indent in stasckoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out the reason.

first.. its time limit issue
so i changed the time limit to below

```
foreach($data_array as $item){
            set_time_limit(400);//this did send out the output
```

and second issue was related to text field from sql

```
htmlentities($value);
```

now solved.